# "$n$ is even iff $n^2$ is even" and other simple statements to teach proof-writing

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, big-list, education

I am supposed to teach undergraduate students who do not major in mathematics and I would like to give them a short introduction to mathematical *reasoning* and to the concept of *proof*. I am looking for very simple mathematical statements **(true or false)** to help them get familiar with logic and proof writing.

I am not sure if what I ask is clear, so here are some ideas I came up with:

1. Let $n$ be an integer. If $n$ is a multiple of $42$, then $n$ is even.
2. Let $n$ be an integer. If $n$ is a multiple of $43$, then $n$ is odd.
3. If $x$ is a positive real number, then $x^2 \geq x$.
4. For all $n \in \Bbb Z$, $n$ is even iff $n^2$ is even.
5. There is no $x \in \Bbb Q$ such that $x^2 = 2$.
6. There exist irrational numbers $\alpha,\beta > 0$ such that $\alpha^\beta$ is rational.
7. For all $x \in \Bbb R$, if [for all $\epsilon > 0$, $|x| < \epsilon$], then $x = 0$.
8. There exists $m \in \Bbb Z$ such that, for all $n \in \Bbb Z$, one has $n \leq m$.
9. $(-1)\times (-1) = 1$
10. For all $x \in \Bbb R$, one has $0\times x = 0$. (proposed by Robert Auffarth)
11. Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $x$ is real and $x^n=0$ then $x = 0$. (ibidem)
12. Suppose $b,d \neq 0$ and $\dfrac{a}{b} = \dfrac{c}{d}$. Then $\dfrac{a}{b} + \dfrac{c}{d} = \dfrac{a+c}{b+d}$.

It would be great to cover different type of statements.

Comment: Are the undergraduates you are asking these questions to studying in the sciences or humanities? (This question for the technicality of possible questions). Either way, I wish you luck in introducing them to the 'fun' part of mathematics!

Comment: Let $x$ be a real number.  Then $x>3$ or $x<6$.  (Note the use of inclusive or.)

Comment: These students major in Economics, so they already have some background in maths but they were never really asked to prove (or understand) anything.

Comment: I predict that the students won't like this exercise. If they don't intend to be research mathematicians, they will regard the writing of proofs as pointless formalism. They will say that the propositions are "obvious", and it's a waste of time learning the special language/symbology and structure required to "prove" them the way mathematicians do.

Comment: I'd replace 12 with *then $a = c$ and $b = d$*.

Comment: If $0<x<1$, $x^2>x$ is false, so #3 is not a true statement.

Comment: @wilsonw And 2 is true? I see this as a list of simple statements, some true and some not, intended to show how important it is to prove things, and not just have a "hunch".

Comment: For (9) and (10) I think it is essential to discuss on which basis these would have to be proved. If one does not want to have such discussions, then they may not be good choices.

Comment: You might like to look through the statements proved in [tinyproof](https://twitter.com/tinyproof). Some are surely too advanced -- but the ones that aren't clearly admit short proofs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I left the following exercises for a maths education calculus class --- mainly to test their knowledge of the definitions actually. A few soft questions and maybe more material covered than what you are talking about but many are good proof-writing exercises.

**EDIT:** I have added some more calculus problems after 36... this time without italics.

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\raw}{\rightarrow}$ $\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$ $\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}$ $\newcommand{\Raw}{\Rightarrow}$

1. Suppose that $f:\R\raw\R$ and define a function $g:\R\raw\R$ by $g(x)=1/f(x)$. Prove that $g$ has no *roots*.
2. Let $n\in\N$ and $f:\R\raw\R$. Prove that $k$ is a *root* of $[f(x)]^n$ if and only if $k$ is a *root* of $f$.
3. Let $f:\R\raw\R$. Prove that if $k$ is a *root* of $f$, then $0$ is a *root* of $f(x+k)$.
4. Prove that the product of two *even* functions is an *even* function.
5. Prove that the composition of two *even* functions is an *even* function.
6. Use the unit circle to  prove that the cosine function is an *even* function.
7. Prove that the product of two *odd* functions is an *even* function.
8. Suppose that $f:\R\raw\R$ is an *odd* function defined on the entire real line. Prove that $f$ has a root.
9. Using the fact that sine is an *odd* function, prove that the tangent function is *odd*.
10. Prove that $g:\R\raw\R$, defined by $g(x)=-x$ is *decreasing*.
11. Give an example of a function $f:\R\raw\R$ which is both *increasing* and *decreasing* for all $x\in\R$.
12. Give an example of a function that is *strictly increasing* for all $x\in\R$ but has no roots.
13. Suppose that $f:\R\raw\R$ is *strictly increasing* on a non-empty closed interval $[a,b]\subset\R$. Show that if $a\leq x_1<x_2\leq b$, then the (secant) line joining $(x_1,f(x_1))$ to $(x_2,f(x_2))$ has positive slope.
14. Suppose that $g:\R\raw\R$ is strictly decreasing and has a root at $a\in\R$. Prove that $g$ has no other roots.
15. Suppose that $f:\R\raw\R$ is a positive *increasing* function and that $g:\R\raw\R$ is a positive *decreasing* function. Prove that $q=f/g$, $q(x)=f(x)/g(x)$ is an *increasing* function.
16. Use the formula for the roots of a *quadratic* function $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ to find an expression for the sum of the roots of $p$; and the product of the roots of $p$.
17. Suppose that $q(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is a *quadratic* function with real roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Use the fact that quadratic functions are symmetric about the line $x=-b/2a$ --- and that  their maxima/ minima are found there to find an expression for $\alpha+\beta$.
18. Let $r(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ be a *quadratic* function. Use the factor theorem to find an expression for the sum of the roots of $r$; and the product of the roots of $r$.
19. Prove that all *polynomials* of odd degree have at least one root.
20. Prove the factor theorem for the *polynomial* $c(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$.
21. Give an example of degree $4$ *polynomials* $p$ and $q$ such that $p+q$ is a *polynomial* of degree $3$.
22. Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are polynomials and let $r$ be the *rational* function defined by $r(x)=p(x)/q(x)$. Prove that if $k$ is a root of $r$ then $k$ is a root of $p$. By finding a counterexample, show that the converse does not hold.
23. Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are polynomials and let $r$ be the *rational* function $r(x)=p(x)/q(x)$. If $q(a)=0$, then $r(a)$ is not defined at $a$ and hence discontinuous at $a$. Find examples of polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that: (a) $r$ is continuous, and (b) $r$ is not continuous---but is bounded (there exists a positive number $M>0$ such that $|r(x)|<M$ for all $x\in\R$).
24. Prove that $|x^2+1|=x^2+1$ for all $x\in\R$.
25. Prove that the *absolute value* function is even.
26. Suppose that $f:\R\raw \R$ has the property that $f(x)<0$ for all $x\in\R$. Describe the relationship between the graph of $f(x)$  and the graph of $|f(x)|$.
27. Let $k\in\R$ be a constant and $a\in\R$. Use the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition of a *limit* to prove that
    $$\lim_{x\raw a}k=k\text{, and }\lim_{x\raw a}x=a.$$
28. Suppose that $f:\R\raw\R$ and
    $$\lim_{x\raw 1}f(x)=0.$$
    Does this imply that $1$ is a root of $f$?
29. Show that there are two values of $a\in\R$ such that the *left- and right-handed limits* of $f:\R\raw\R$ at $x=1$ agree where:
    $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}(ax)^2 & \text{ if }x<1
        \\ ax+6 & \text{ if }x\geq 1\end{array}\right.$$
    Produce a rough sketch of $f$ in each case.
30. Assuming we know what $2^x$ is, we can define a function $f:\R\raw\R$ by:
    $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+2^{-1/x}}$$
    Sketch an argument that suggests that the *left- and right-hand limits of* $f(x)$ at $0$ are, respectively, $0$ and $1$.
31. Construct a function $f:\R\raw\R$ such that
    $$\lim_{x\raw0^-}f(x)=+\infty\text{ , and }\lim_{x\raw 0^+}f(x)=1.$$
32. Suppose that $f:\R\raw\R$ and that
    $$\forall\varepsilon>0,\,\exists\,\delta>0\text{ such that if }0<|x|<\delta\Rightarrow|f(x)|<\varepsilon.$$
    Does this imply that
    $$\lim_{x\raw 0}f(x)=0.$$
33. For all real numbers $x,\,y\in\R$ with $x\neq y$, there exists a fraction between $x$ and $y$ --- i.e. a $q\in(x,y)$.  Consider the function
    $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1&\text{ if }x\in\Q
    \\0 & \text{ if }x\not\in\Q\end{array}\right.$$
    Prove that $f$ is not *continuous* at *any* point.
34. Consider the function
    $$g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x&\text{ if }x\in\Q
    \\0 & \text{ if }x\not\in\Q\end{array}\right.$$
    Prove that $g$ is *continuous* at $0$.
35. Suppose that functions $f_1:\R\raw \R$ and $f_2:\R\raw\R$ have the property that, for $i=1,2$
    $$f_i(x)=f_i(y)\Raw x=y.$$
    Prove that $f=f_1\circ f_2$ has this property also.
36. Find a set $A\subseteq\R$, and functions $f:A\raw\R$ and $g:\R\raw \R$ such that $(g\circ f)(x)=x$ for all $x\in A$ but that there exists a $y\in \R$ such that $(f\circ g)(y)\neq y$.
37. Suppose that $f:[0,1]\raw[0,1]$ is continuous and strictly increasing on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Suppose further that $g:[0,1]\raw[0,1]$ is a  function such that
    $$(g\circ f)(x)=x$$
    for all $x\in[0,1]$. How is the graph of $g$ related  to the graph of $f$.
38. Prove that a continuous function is  continuous on any non-empty closed interval $[a,b]\subset \R$.
39. Construct a function which is not continuous (everywhere) but is  {continuous on} $[0,1]$.
40. The singleton set $\{x\}\subset\R$ is equal to the closed interval $[x,x]$. Verify that all the conclusions of the  Intermediate Value Theorem hold when $f:\{x\}\raw\R$ is a  continuous function got by restricting a continuous function $f:\R\raw\R$ to $\{x\}$. Find  {ALL} such continuous functions $\{x\}\raw\R$.
41. Prove that the  Mean Value Theorem holds on any non-empty closed interval for a smooth function $f:\R\raw\R$.
42. Find the  local maxima and minima of the constant function $f(x)=0$.
43. Show that $f:\R\raw\R$, $f(x)=x^4+12x^3+54x^2-12x+5$ is  concave up on $\R$.
44. Prove that $\tan x$ has a  vertical asymptote at $x=\pi/2$.
45. Give an example of a function which is  continuous on $(0,1]$ but not  on $[0,1]$.
46. Use the  Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that $\sqrt{2}\in\R$ exists.
47. Use the  Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that if $f:[a,b]\raw\R$ and $g:[a,b]\raw\R$ are continuous functions such that $f(a)=g(b)$ and $f(b)=g(a)$, then there exists a point $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=g(c)$.
48. It can be shown that a continuous function obtains its  absolute maximum and minimum on finite unions of closed intervals. Consider the set $S$ defined by:
    \begin{align*}
        S&=[0,2\pi]\cup\left[2\pi,2\pi+\frac{1}{2\pi}\right]\cup\left[3\pi,3\pi+\frac{1}{3\pi}\right]\cup\left[4\pi,4+\frac{1}{4\pi}\right]\cup\cdots\cup\left[100\pi,100\pi+\frac{1}{100\pi}\right],
        \\ &=[0,2\pi]\cup\left(\bigcup_{i=2}^{100}\left[i\pi,i\pi+\frac{1}{i\pi}\right]\right).
        \end{align*}
    Find the absolute maxima and minima of $\sin:S\raw\R$.
49. If $f:(a,b)\raw\R$ is a smooth function such that $f'=0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ then $f$ is constant on $(a,b)$. Find an example of a differentiable function $g:\R\raw\R$ such that
    $$\lim_{x\raw\infty}g'(x)=0\text{ , but}\lim_{x\raw\infty}g(x)$$
    is not a constant.
50. Sketch continuous functions $f_i:[0,1]\raw\R$ for $i=1,2,3,4,\dots$ such that $f_i$ has $i$ stationary points; i.e. solutions to $f'(c)=0$ for $c\in(0,1)$.
51. Is it possible for a function $f:\R\raw\R$ to have a  local maximum/ minimum at a point $a\in\R$ where $f$ is discontinuous?.
52. In the proof of the  Closed Interval Method, we make the assumption that $f:[a,b]\raw\R$ is continuous. Is this assumption necessary?.
53. Let $\varepsilon\in (0,1)$ be a constant. Using algebraic techniques, find the
                 critical points of $f:[0,1]\raw\R$
                $$f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0 & \text{ if }-1\leq x<-\varepsilon
                    \\[1.5ex]\ \frac{1}{\varepsilon}x+1 & \text{ if }-\varepsilon\leq x<0
                    \\[1.5ex] -\frac{1}{\varepsilon}x+1 & \text{ if }0\leq x<\varepsilon
                    \\[1.5ex] 0 &\text{ if }\varepsilon\leq x\leq 1
                    \end{array}\right.$$
54. Construct a function $f:\R\raw\R$ that is  twice differentiable but not  three-times differentiable.
55. Show that
    $$\lim_{h\raw0}\frac{\cos(\pi+h)-\cos(\pi)}{h}=0.$$
    Show that if $f:[a,b]\raw\R$ is  twice differentiable, there exists a point $c\in(a,b)$ such that
    $$f''(c)=\frac{f'(b)-f'(a)}{b-a}$$
56. Suppose that a smooth function $f:[-1,1]\raw\R$ is  concave down on $[-1,1]$ and further that $f'(0)=0$. Draw a sketch suggesting that $f$ attains its absolute maximum at $0$.
57. Use the geometric definition of  concavity to show that $f(x)=|x|$ is  concave up on $\R$.
58. Show that $|x|$ is an  asymptotic of $\sqrt{x^2+3}$.
59. Explain why there is no polynomial  asymptotic of $\sin x$.
60. Find all  vertical asymptotes of $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$.
61. Use the  Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that if $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is a continuous function, then $f$ has a  fixed point; i.e. a point $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=x$.
62. Suppose that $f:[a,b]\raw \R$ is a differentiable function such that $f'(x)\leq K$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Prove that $f(a)+K(b-a)$ is an upper bound for the {absolute maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$} [HINT: Assume that $f(x)>f(a)+K(b-a)$ for some $x\in[a,b]$ and show that this contradicts the  Mean Value Theorem.].
63. Call a non-empty set of points $\{x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}\subset\R$ an  antipodal set for $f:\R\raw\R$ if the tangents to $f$ at $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ are all parallel. Prove that an antipodal sets of a cubic function contain at most two elements.
64. Verify  Rolles's Theorem for $\sin:[0,\pi]\raw\R$ geometrically by considering the unit circle with parametric equation $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.
65. Let $[a,b]$ be a non-empty closed interval and consider $\sin:[a,b]\raw\R$. Explain why $\sin$ satisfies the hypothesis of the  Mean Value Theorem. Apply the Mean Value Theorem to show that there exists an $x\in(a,b)$ such that
            $$|\cos(x)|=\left|\frac{\sin(b)-\sin(a)}{b-a}\right|.$$
    Now use this result to show that for any $x_1,\,x_2\in \R$
    $$|\sin (x_2)-\sin(x_1)|\leq |x_2-x_1|.$$
    We could then use this result to prove that $\sin$ is a continuous function. What would be wrong with the proof?
66. In this exercise we see why we might call the quantity
     $$\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$
     the  average slope across $[a,b]$ when we talk about the  Mean Value Theorem. Let $f:[a,b]\raw\R$ be a differentiable function. Partition the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ equally spaced points:
    $$a=:x_0<x_1<x_2<\cdots x_n:=b.$$
    If $[a,b]$ is divided into $n$ sub-intervals then each will have width $h=(b-a)/n$ ---
    so that $x_i=a+ih$. Produce a sketch of a smooth function $f:[a,b]\raw\R$ and a partition of $[a,b]$. Now for large $n$, and hence intervals of small length,  smooth curves look like lines so approximate the slope of $f$ on the interval $[x_{i-1},x_{i}]$ by the secant line joining $(x_{i-1},f(x_{i-1}))$ to $(x_{i},f(x_{i}))$ (a sketch should help):
    $$f'(x)\approx \frac{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})}{h}\,\text{ , for }x\in[x_{i-1},x_i].$$
    Now average over all of the $n$ sub-intervals:
    $$\text{average}(f')\approx\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})}{h}\right)}{n}.$$
    Now use the relationship between $a,\,b,\,n$ and $h$ and telescoping series techniques(see Wikipedia) to show that
    $$\text{average}(f')\approx \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.$$
    To make this interpretation precise --- by taking $n\raw\infty$ --- we actually have to use the  Mean Value Theorem! More of this in Integration.
67. Argue that if $f:\R\raw\R$ is a smooth, even function such that the only solution to $f'(x)=0$ is $x=0$, then $x=0$ cannot be a  saddle point (a point $a\in\R$ such that $f'(a)=0$ but $a$ is not a local maxima or minima). Suppose there is a  {local maximum} at $x=0$. Explain why this is an absolute maximum for $f$ on $\R$.
68. Construct a function with  vertical asymptotes at $x=0,1,2,3,4,4,\dots,10^6$.

Comment: FYI, your item 1. is discussed [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2408930/).

Answer (score 3):

- There are an infinite number of primes (i.e., the proof by Euclid).
- $a^p\equiv a\mod p$ implies $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 3):

(Related to your #12)

Let $a,b,c,d$ be positive integers.  Prove that if $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$ then
$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{a+c}{b+d}<\frac{c}{d}$.  (Similarly for $>$ and $=$.)

Answer (score 2):

An interesting example of a statement they could try to prove is:

> Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $2k$ is odd, then $k$ must be odd.

This seems to be made for contradiction or contrapositive, which work well. However, while it is a true statement, it could be improved. This could lead to a useful discussion about strengthening hypotheses/conclusions, the difference between necessary and sufficient conditions, and vacuous statements. Some of these things may be too advanced for the students you're teaching, but I think the example is simple enough for them to understand if you want to challenge them.

Comment: I think that it would be a *very* bad idea to use this as an example in a *short* introduction: unless a great deal of time is spent on it and the issues that it raises, it is almost certain to generate an enormous amount of confusion.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see where you are coming from; I did say that it may be too advanced. I imagine something like this would come after a couple of weeks. I suppose it just depends on the level of the students and how short the introduction is.

Answer (score 1):

This may be too hard for non-math students: Any real polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots.

Other fun ones that students know but don't know how to prove are:

1. Prove that $0\cdot x=0$ for any real number $x$.
2. Prove that $1\cdot x=x$ for any real number $x$.
3. If $x^n=0$ for a real number $x$, then $x=0$.

Comment: Ok, I put some other ones that my calculus students get mad at! They always say things like "We've known this since high school, why do we have to prove it!"

Comment: I like 1 and 3 very much, but I think 2 is more of a definition/axiom (1 is the unit of the ring $(\Bbb R,+,\times)$). Do you expect something involving the construction of the multiplication of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry about this. This is usually taken as an axiom!

Comment: In the same vein I like "prove $(-1)\times (-1) = 1$".

Comment: Yes, these simple proofs get students to think in a different way, and they start acquiring nice tricks.

Answer (score 0):

For each $\epsilon >0$, there exists $c$ such that for each $x > c $, $\left| \dfrac{3x-1}{2x+11} -\dfrac{3}{2}\right| < \epsilon$.